# Has the luminosity of the universe ever been larger than $\frac{c^5}{4G}$?

Tags: cosmology

$\frac{c^5}{4G}$ is about $10^{52}\,\rm W$. The value is sometimes called the maximum power, e.g. by Gibbons.

Has the luminosity of the universe ever been that high or higher? Is there a large sphere for which all the radiation and mass that comes out of it is larger than $\frac{c^5}{4G}$?

Comment: Why the factor of $\frac14$?

Comment: Do you intend a restriction to one Hubble zone, i.e. an observable universe? If you include the $10^{120}$ factor or so by which the universe inflated early on, the luminosity of all stars will be far larger than $\frac{c^5}{4G}$.

Comment: Can you give a reference?

Comment: Read [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.03271) and [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9912110). aka 'Roughly speaking, the Big Bang saturated the absolute bound' (and the OP is off by a factor of 2)

Comment: Ok. The references claim c^5/2G, but they have mistakes. c^5/4G is correct.  But 10^120 times more than c^5/4G is nonsense.

Comment: No, not $10^{120}\frac{c^5}{4G}$; what I'm saying is if you sum the luminosity of all stars in this Hubble zone, _then_ also correct for the universe's inferred inflation, $\frac{c^5}{G}$ is small potatoes.

Comment: Are you saying that there ever was more than c^5/4G? That is the reference I am looking for ... (I do not believe it, btw.)

Comment: By "ever was", do you mean per Hubble zone, or on a larger scale? Each Hubble zone's total stellar luminosity will be a few orders of magnitude less than $c^5/G$ (please put dollar signs around that). I apologize for apparently misremembering the volume factor: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflationary_epoch) says it should be about $10^{78}$ but I can't find their source, while Figure 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/PS_cache/astro-ph/pdf/0305/0305179v1.pdf) makes it $10^{90}$.